# On drupal I have installed civicrm module.I want to show civicrm contact on drupal view.I have created a view for it, but it is not displaying contact

Tags: drupal-views, civicrm-contact

on drupal, I have installed CiviCRM, view module. I want to display a CiviCRM contact on drupal view.
for that, I have created a view for CiviCRM contact, but on view, it is not showing CiviCRM contact. can anyone help me

Comment: What Drupal version is this?

Answer (score 2):

Have you added [CMS integration](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/integration/drupal/views/#configuration) in your drupal settings.php?

Comment: Whether you need this depends on your version of Drupal.